# Argument does not correspond to a format parameter; Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am learning C#, and have been practicing variations of Inheritance.  The others have worked, but this one throws an error that states an argument does not correspond to a formal parameter.  This issue only occurs when I add the derived class in, and I have spent an hour trying to fix to no avail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
      public class Parent
      {
          public string fName, lName;
          public int employeeId;
          public Parent(string fName, string lName, int employeeId)
          {
              this.fName = fName;
              this.lName = lName;
              this.employeeId = employeeId;
          }
          public decimal Money(decimal d)
          {
              return d;
          }          
      }
      public class Child : Parent
      {

      }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Parent p1 = new Parent("Ted", "Baxter", 5432);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p1.fName, p1.lName, p1.employeeId);

            Console.WriteLine((p1.Money(5.50m)));
        Child c1 = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(c1.fName);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every constructor calles it's base class constructor either by explicit code:

```
public ctor(int parameter) : base(parameter)
```

or implicitly:

```
public ctor(int parameter) {}
```

This will actually be compiled as:

```
public ctor(int parameter) : base()
```

Please note that if you do not explicitly state what overload you want to execute from your base class, the parameter-less constructor will be chosen by default, even if your child constructor have the exact same signature of one of the parent's constructors.

In your `Child` class you don't specify a constructor so the c# compiler provides a default constructor for you. (Note - static classes can't have constructors, only static constructors. See comment by Jeppe Stig Nielsen).

A default constructor is a parameter-less constructor that initializes no values in the instance of the class and of course, calls the base parameter-less constructor. 
Since your base class have no parameter-less constructor, you get a compilation error.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if your `class` is _not_ `static`, and if you specify _no_ constructors yourself, then the compiler will generate one for you that is equivalent to `public ClassName() : base() { }` (for `abstract` classes it is `protected` instead of `public`).

Answer (score 0):

One of the base class' constructors must be called by the child class. When you have a parameterless constructor, the compiler takes care of this for you, but in your case you do not:

`public Parent(string fName, string lName, int employeeId)`

You can rewrite your child class to pass the parameters to the base:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string fName, string lName, int employeeId) : base(fName, lName, employeeId)
    {

    }
}
```

or you can create a parameterless constructor and put dummy values in:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child() : base(string.Empty, string.Empty, -1)
    {

    }
}
```

or a combination of both.

Note that the *base class'* constructor will always be called before the child class' constructor.